# Help in Finding Specific Solutions to Diff. Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

> Find the general solution for the following differential equation: 
>   $$f''(t) + f(t) = 3 \sin(2t) + 1, \ f(0) = 3, f′
> (0) = 0$$

So, I understand how to find the homogeneous solution to this equation. Given the form $f''(t) + f(t)$, you can deduce that it is in the form of $A\cos(t)+B\sin(t)$. However, I am having difficulty in finding how the specific solution to the $3\sin(2t)$ term comes into play.
I know the answer is $2\cos(t) + 2\sin(t) - \sin(2t) + 1$, but I don't know how to find the specific solution with regard to the initial conditions. Can someone please please help me?

Comment: Hint: undetermined coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$$f′′(t) + f(t) = 3 sin(2t) + 1$$
the characteristic polynomial is

$$r^2+1=0 \implies r= \pm i \implies f(t)= c_1\cos(t)+c_2 \sin(t)$$
for the particular solution try

$$y_p= A\sin(2t)+B\cos(2t) \text { or simply } y_p=A\sin(2t)$$
$$f′′(t) + f(t) = 3 sin(2t)$$
$$(A\sin(2t))'' +A\sin(2t) = 3 sin(2t) $$
$$-4A\sin(2t)+A\sin(2t)=3\sin(2t) \implies A=-1$$
$$ \implies  y_p=-\sin(2t)$$
For the constanttry $f_p=C$ so that
$$f′′(t) + f(t) =  1$$
$$(C)'' + C = 1 \implies C=1$$
$$y_p=-\sin(2t)+1$$
Therefore,
$$f(t)= c_1\cos(t)+c_2 \sin(t) -\sin(2t)+1$$
Try to find the coefficients with the conditions you are given..
$$
\begin{cases}
f(0)=3 \\
f'(0)=0
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
f(0)=3 \implies f(0)= c_1\cos(0)+c_2 \sin(0) -\sin(0)+1=3 \\
f'(0)=0 \implies f'(0)= -c_1\sin(0)+c_2 \cos(0) -2\cos(0)+1=0
\end{cases}
$$
It's just a linear system that's easy to solve...

Comment: I'm with you until you added the -4Asin(2t)... line. Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Differentiate twice $A\sin(2t)$ @ChrisR

Comment: I added some lines @ChrisR